# How to sort object exactly like Blender sorts object "Alphabetically"?

Tags: python

I have the sorting like this:

```
objects= col.all_objects[:]
objects.sort(key=lambda x: x.name.upper(), reverse=False)
```

I've used `.upper()` because blender's sort is case-insensitive. But in the same time non-Latin sorting is case-sensitive, so I get wrong sorting with `.upper()` in non-Latin object names:

[image]

Console output:

[image]

Other nasty thing that Blender uses case-sensitive when sorts name.00x things:

[image]

How it is supposed to sort objects to match them with Blender's internal sorting?

Comment: I think the relevant function is [`outliner_sort`](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/5f16e24cc9ac4f620df2ab65d5a7b9ae4f99f203/source/blender/editors/space_outliner/outliner_tree.cc#L1087). Also see [`BLI_strcasecmp_natural`](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/5f16e24cc9ac4f620df2ab65d5a7b9ae4f99f203/source/blender/blenlib/intern/string.c#L718).

Comment: How Can I use it in Python?

Comment: I don't know if there's any way other than porting the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution from me. Instead of thinking about nasty sorting in Blender, just make unified names:

```
blocks = col.all_objects[:]
    for block in blocks:
        block.name = block.name.title()
```

And then sort.